# Why is devise adding prefix 'devise' to every controller in link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nitrousio

I am doing a hobby project on Nitrous.io
I just installed devise for authentication. Before installing that gem everything was working fine, but now devise is putting a 'devise' prefix to every controller.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'site/about'
  get 'site/help'
  get 'admin/index'

  resources :categories
  resources :businesses

  devise_for :users

  root :to=> 'site#home'
end
```